# C and C++ compiler give different messages for the following code, why?

Tags: c++, c

I was asked to give the output of the following code in an interview.

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int *p = &a + 1;
printf("%d, %d", *(a+1), *(p - 1));
```

I said I could not determine the result of the second one, so I failed the interview.

When I got back to home, and tried to compile the code, g++ will report an error, but gcc will only give a warning. The result printed is '2,5'.

Anyone knows why the C and C++ compiler behave differently on this?

Comment: What are the error and warning reported ?

Comment: Is that your typo? Because p is undefined. Did you mean to say p2 - 1?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: Care to share what the error/warning you get is?

Comment: The question does make sense. There may be a couple of typos in it though.

Comment: @Nick: No, it doesn't. Not only does the testcase not match the question, but the fundamental nature of the question is wrong; it seems to assume that g++ and gcc should always give the same output, which is nonsensical. Instead, it should list _expected behaviours_ and _observed behaviours_ and then ask a question.

Comment: are you sure there is no typo in code?

Comment: Oh, I thought the question was "Why do the C and C++ compilers behave differently on this?"

Comment: @dauphic Seems a legitimate question to me if their business is writing compilers.

Answer (score 10):

`a` is an array of integers, which converts to a pointer to the first element when needed. `a+1` invokes that conversion, and gives a pointer to the second element.

`&a` is a pointer to the array itself, not to the first element of it, so `&a + 1` points beyond the end of the array (to the point where the second array would be, if it were a 2-dimensional array).

The code then converts that pointer (of type `int (*)[5]`) to a pointer to an integer (type `int*`). C++ doesn't allow such a conversion without an explicit `reinterpret_cast`, while C is more lenient in the pointer conversions it allows.

Finally (assuming that `p` and `p2` are supposed to be the same thing), `p - 1` points to the last element of `a`.

Comment: The C compiler should've issued a warning, however.

Comment: @PerJohansson it issues, you just need to adjust compiler warning levels

Answer (score 5):

Well, `a` is array of 5 ints, so `&a` is a pointer to array of 5 ints. in C++, you can't assign that address in a `int*` without cast it. gcc (in C language) gives only warning, but I think that is not valid C.

For the code:

`&a+1` is the next array after `a`, meaning, the address of the 6th element in `a`, so `p-1` is the address of the 5th element of `a`.

(I'm not sure if `&a+1` is legal. it's the address of the element that is after the array, which is usually legal, but since `&a` is not an array, it may be illegal.)

Comment: I think `&a+1` is legal. For the purposes of pointer arithmetic, an object is treated as an array of size 1. The array `a` is of course an object in addition to being an array, so `&a+1` is a legal pointer one-past-the-end of it. That is, one-past-the-end of an array of type `int[1][5]`. So as you've said, it refers to the same address as the one-past-the-end pointer `a+5` but with different type. You can just as well do `int i = 0; &i+1;`.

Answer (score 2):

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int *p = &a + 1;
```

This is invalid C code.

The expression `&a + 1` is of type `int (*)[5]`. You cannot assign an expression of type `int (*)[5]` to an `int *`.

Except with the generic object pointer type `void *`, there is no implicit conversion between object pointers. A cast is required to initialize `p` with `&a + 1` value.

**Where does C says this declaration is invalid?**

```
int *p = &a + 1;
```

in the constraints of the assignment operator:

> (C99, 6.5.16.1p1) "both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right"

And an `int` and an array type are not compatible types (see 6.2.7p1 for more on type compatibility).

well also, it is an initialization not an assignment, but the same constraint applies:

> (C99, 6.7.8p11) "The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces. The initial value of the object is that of the expression (after conversion); the same type constraints and conversions as for simple assignment apply, taking the type of the scalar to be the unqualified version of its declared type."

Comment: A cast is required ... to force the compiler to stay quiet even when the operation is invalid :)

Comment: @WilliBurkhardt it is invalid in C89, in C99 and in C11. Long story short, it is an initialization but you have to look on the constraints of the assignment operator.

Comment: @WilliBurkhardt it's not valid code but some bad implicit conversion are making this possible

Comment: @WilliBurkhardt the *after conversion* regards the arithmetic types as there is no implicit or automatic conversions for object pointer types as far as I remember. The conversions in 6.3.2.3p5, p6 and p7 are not implicit and require a cast.

Comment: @WilliBurkhardt The "otherwise" part applies and this simply says that `&a` is a pointer to the `a` array. I see no relevance of this paragraph in the discussion about the invalid code.

Comment: ouah: There are implicit conversions between `void *` and other pointer types, but that's all.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ compiler gave an error because `&a` evaluates to `int(*)[5]`, which is a pointer to 5 integers, and you're attempting to assign it to an `int*`.

If you did fix the type, this code would print the second item in the array, followed by the address of the array.

My guess is that C decays the array into a pointer, resulting in `&a` evaluating to `int**`, and allows that to be assigned to `int*`. However, I don't do much C, so someone else may know better.